# Does JasperServer support URL encoding?

Tags: web-services, get, jasperserver

I currently have some problems with my jasperserver 5.0.0.

When I try to get a report using the rest_v2 API, I have an error.

With this url : 
        http://myjasper.net:8081/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/AP/Offre.PDF%3FtarificationId=3601844

-> error :

```
<errorDescriptor>
<errorCode>webservices.error.errorExportingReportUnit</errorCode>
<parameters>
<parameter>
Export format pdf?tarificationid=3601844 not supported or misconfigured
</parameter>
</parameters>
</errorDescriptor>
```

With this url : 
    http://myjasper.net:8081/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/reports/AP/Offre.PDF?tarificationId=3601844

-> it works !!

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the JasperReports Server Web Services Guide:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-web-service-guide

On page 21:

> Arguments are passed in the URL with the conventional syntax:
>   http://:/jasperserver[-pro]/rest//path/to/object?=&=&...

You're not actually passing a question mark, you're telling the web service to get ready to accept your arguments. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp for more information on GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all URL encoded by "encodeURIComponent" or similar function, which encoding "&", "?" and other URL symbols. These functions have to use for encoding url parameters and not for all URL.